# Publishing Through Blogs/Story Equivalent of Webcomic?

Tags: publishing, blog

I really want to publish my work somewhere online. That being said, recently, I've had quite of an interest in webcomics--however, I can't draw, and I prefer full on writing. Is there a possible way to just start a writing blog with a similar concept, or are there other ways to publish my writing and make the platform completely my own? (Sorry if I'm not making any sense. :p) Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you looking for examples of writing blogs, or only for explanations on how to make your own?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things you can do for this.

1. Start your own personal blog. There are lots of free services like [Blogger](http://blogger.com/) (you'll need a Google account to use this), [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/).com (careful, NOT .org), [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com/), etc.
2. Publish with a free fiction-posting service, like [Wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com/).
3. Work with an artist to create a web comic in which you are the writer, and the artist does the artwork. Which leads me to...
4. [DeviantART](http://deviantart.com/) is a good place for both writers and artists, and for them to collaborate and get their work seen. Lots of working pros out there in all fields of creative arts. It's a wonderful resource.

Hope that helps some, and good luck. Most of all, have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do. If you want to make comics but can't draw there are various comic creation sites, such as bitstrips, and software packages that help you by providing the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some talented people who do both art and writing, it's quite common in comics for one person to write and one person to do the art.  I'm not personally tapped into that community, but I'd imagine you could locate someone interested in collaborating if you looked hard enough.

If you're not necessarily interested in a comic, but just want to write your own stories as a serialized blog format, there are people who have done that very successfully.  I believe the award-winning *[Fairyland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairyland_%28series%29)* series began that way.

The key for success in any serialized writing is sustained, consistent, regular updates and high writing quality.